# How to expand a SVG responsively?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm using a SVG under an hamburger menu so when the user clicks that menu, the SVG expands and fills the entire screen with the options on it. I'm using scale() for that so basically what happens is that the SVG has a scale of 1 and when the user clicks on the menu the SVG gets a scale(35).

Now the problem. That scale(35) doesn't fill the entire screen on bigger resolutions or even on some mobile resolutions with bigger height. If I set the scale for something that will ensure me that will cover most of the screens, like scale(70), this will make the close animation really messy for going through such a big scale to 1. How can I expand this SVG with a smooth animation so it fills every type of screen?

***EDIT - Added code with a simple and fast example downthere***

Below are some images that explain what happens.

Closed menu / SVG with scale(1)
[image: Close menu / SVG with scale(1)]

Opened menu / SVG with scale(70)
[image: Opened menu / SVG with scale(70)]

Menu closing / SVG going from scale(70) to scale(1) and looking messy
[image: Menu closing / SVG going from scale(70) to scale(1) and looking messy]

```js
function menuOnClick() {
  document.getElementById("menu-bar").classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("nav").classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById('blob').classList.toggle("change-bg");
}
```

```css
#menu {
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu-bar {
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.bar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00d1a9;;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#bar1 {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

#bar3 {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.nav {
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  display: none;
}

.nav ul {
  padding: 0 22px;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.nav li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-bg, #menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.change {
  display: block;
}

.change .bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.change #bar1 {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.change #bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change #bar3 {
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.change-bg {
  transform: scale(70);
}
.blob {
  margin-top:-32px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s linear;
  transition: all 0.75s linear;
  display: block;
  will-change: auto;
    filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -moz-filter: blur(0);
  -ms-filter: blur(0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0');
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu-bar" onclick="menuOnClick()">
    <div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</div>
                                <svg class="blob" id="blob" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="265.42" height="151.973" viewBox="0 0 265.42 151.973">
                                    <title>Menu Blob</title>
                                    <desc>The blob that grows to be the menu background</desc>
                                    <path class="blobPath" id="blobPath" shape-rendering="auto" d="M-1377.154,10877.442c-10.882-7.812-24.262-11.1-36.627-16.251s-24.764-13.355-28.853-26.112c-.135.766,251.322-30.752,251.3-30.855s-9.766,33.5-15.478,42.831c-9.83,16.055-20.015,32.053-32.926,45.756a125.25,125.25,0,0,1-18.85,16.492,89.6,89.6,0,0,1-28.133,13.538,70.507,70.507,0,0,1-29.47,1.6,56.7,56.7,0,0,1-24.487-10C-1354.7,10904.193-1363.044,10887.567-1377.154,10877.442Z" transform="translate(2763.902 -10547.315) rotate(7)" />
                                </svg>

<div class="menu-bg" id="menu-bg"></div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve].  But based solely on what you have already posted, the answer is likely going to involve scaling the *contents* of the SVG, not the whole SVG.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau added an example. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is how to scale the blob responsively rather than have just one scale value which could be too small for very large screens, and conversely cause problems on very small ones when shrinking.

As JS is already being invoked on click we can get the base-size of the blob and see 'how many times' it will fit into the window height and width respectively and use those ratios to calculate a scale that will guarantee the window becomes covered but without huge scaling.

We can do this by calculating a CSS variable in the click event function which will then get used in the change-bg class (but will be ignored when this class is not set). This has the advantage that it will automatically recalculate scale if the window has been resized.

```js
function menuOnClick() {
  document.getElementById("menu-bar").classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("nav").classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById('blob').classList.toggle("change-bg");
  /* added */
  let blob = document.getElementById('blob');
  let rect = blob.getBoundingClientRect();
  document.getElementById('blob').style.setProperty('--scale', Math.max(4*window.innerWidth/rect.width,4*window.innerHeight/rect.height));
}
```

```css
#menu {
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu-bar {
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.bar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00d1a9;;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#bar1 {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

#bar3 {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.nav {
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  display: none;
}

.nav ul {
  padding: 0 22px;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.nav li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-bg, #menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.change {
  display: block;
}

.change .bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.change #bar1 {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.change #bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change #bar3 {
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.blob {
  transform: scale(1); /* added */
  margin-top:-32px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s linear;
  transition: all 0.75s linear;
  display: block;
  will-change: auto;
    filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -moz-filter: blur(0);
  -ms-filter: blur(0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0');
}
.change-bg { /* moved after .blob so takes precedence */
  transform: scale(var(--scale));/* Changed from 70 */
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu-bar" onclick="menuOnClick()">
    <div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</div>
                                <svg class="blob" id="blob" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="265.42" height="151.973" viewBox="0 0 265.42 151.973">
                                    <title>Menu Blob</title>
                                    <desc>The blob that grows to be the menu background</desc>
                                    <path class="blobPath" id="blobPath" shape-rendering="auto" d="M-1377.154,10877.442c-10.882-7.812-24.262-11.1-36.627-16.251s-24.764-13.355-28.853-26.112c-.135.766,251.322-30.752,251.3-30.855s-9.766,33.5-15.478,42.831c-9.83,16.055-20.015,32.053-32.926,45.756a125.25,125.25,0,0,1-18.85,16.492,89.6,89.6,0,0,1-28.133,13.538,70.507,70.507,0,0,1-29.47,1.6,56.7,56.7,0,0,1-24.487-10C-1354.7,10904.193-1363.044,10887.567-1377.154,10877.442Z" transform="translate(2763.902 -10547.315) rotate(7)" />
                                </svg>

<div class="menu-bg" id="menu-bg"></div>
```

Note: this snippet seems to work on different window sizes OK, but in the 'emulator' for mobile on Edge in Windows10 I noticed a single little jerk when shrinking. I cannot explain this. Hope someone can.

Comment: Tested and works! Also tested in the emulator for mobile on Edge/windows 10 and didn't really noticed that "little jerk" you talked about so It works like a charm for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different approach.

```js
document.getElementById("menu-bar").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

#menu {
  position: relative;
}



#blob {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

#blob g {
  fill: #00d1a9;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: 150px 32px;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.open #blob {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.open #blob g {
  transform: scale(20);
}


#menu-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#bar1 {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

#bar3 {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.open #bar1 {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.open #bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open #bar3 {
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotateZ(45deg);
}




.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav ul {
  padding: 0 22px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.nav li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.open .nav {
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <svg class="blob" id="blob" width="256" height="108" viewBox="10 31 256 108">
    <g>
      <path class="blobPath" id="blobPath" shape-rendering="auto" d="M-1377.154,10877.442c-10.882-7.812-24.262-11.1-36.627-16.251s-24.764-13.355-28.853-26.112c-.135.766,251.322-30.752,251.3-30.855s-9.766,33.5-15.478,42.831c-9.83,16.055-20.015,32.053-32.926,45.756a125.25,125.25,0,0,1-18.85,16.492,89.6,89.6,0,0,1-28.133,13.538,70.507,70.507,0,0,1-29.47,1.6,56.7,56.7,0,0,1-24.487-10C-1354.7,10904.193-1363.044,10887.567-1377.154,10877.442Z" transform="translate(2763.902 -10547.315) rotate(7)" />
    </g>
  </svg>

  <div id="menu-bar">
    <div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that different approach! It works really well but doesn't quite do what it's expected as it kinda cuts off the animation and despite that I would have to change a lot of what is already developed to implement that.